# Ratio of primes $(x^2+x+(5+6m))$ to $(x^2+x+(3+6m))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

What I did:

For a large n and $x\leq n$ I counted the number of primes of the form $x^2+x+(5+6m)$ for $m = 0, 1, 2, 3,..., n/2,$ added the number of primes for each m together and called the sum A.

I did the same for $x^2+x+(3+6m)$ and called the sum B.

To show:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{A}{B} = 3.$$

**Example:**

Let A be the total number of primes of the form $x^2+x+(5+6m)$ such that $x < n, m < n/2.$

If $n = 2000, m = 1000.$ For m = 0 there are 308 primes of the form $x^2+x+5$ for $x < 2000.$ For m = 1 there are 507 primes of the form $x^2+x+11$. For each m up to m = 1000 we find the number of primes of the given form for $x < 2000.$ The sum of these, 308+507+...(1001 terms) is A.

For A I get 460848. For B I get 154032. $A/B \approx 2.99.$

\begin{array}{ccc}
A\hspace{30mm}B\\
~~~~k = ~5:~ 308\hspace{10mm}k =~~3: 164\\
~~k = 11:~ 507\hspace{10mm}k = 9:  144\\
~~~k = 17:~ 651\hspace{10mm}k = 15: 128\\
...,\text{etc.}\hspace{10mm}...,\text{etc.}\\
\text{Sums:}~~~460848\hspace{10mm}154032 \\
\end{array}

The guess A/B ~ 3 comes from the table below.

Using the third row of the table below I guess that the ratio for primes of form $x^2+x+(1+14m)$ to those of form $x^2+x+(3+14m)$ is A/B ~ 5/7. And so on.

---

**Comment**: If for $x  < n$ we count the number of primes $\pi_k(n)$ of the form $x^2+x+k,$ k an odd integer and record the ratio $r_k = \frac{\pi_k(n)}{\pi(n)},$ then re-number the list $\{ r_1,r_3,r_5,...\}$ as $\{r_1, r_2, r_3,... \}, $ we can partition the list into 3 sublists: $\{r_1,r_4,..., r_{(1+3m)} \}, \{r_2, r_5,..., r_{(2+3m)} \}, \{r_3,r_6,..., r_{(3+3m)} \}.$ The respective means of these 3 sublists are given in the first row of the table below, from which we get the first conjectural observation above via:

$$\frac{\mu(r_{3+3m})}{\mu(r_{2+3m})} := \frac{\mu(r_{5+6m})}{\mu(r_{3+6m})} = \frac{\mu( \frac{\pi_5(n)}{\pi(n)}+\frac{\pi_{11}(n)}{\pi(n)}+\frac{\pi_{17}(n)}{\pi(n)...})   } {\mu(     \frac{\pi_3(n)}{\pi(n)}+\frac{\pi_{9}(n)}{\pi(n)}+\frac{\pi_{15}(n)}{\pi(n)...})               }= \frac{\frac{1}{(M+1)\pi(n)}\sum_{m=0}^M \pi_{(5+6m)}(n)   }{\frac{1}{(M+1)\pi(n)}\sum_{m=0}^M \pi_{(3+6m)}(n)}$$

$$ = A/B = \frac{3/2}{1/2} $$

The other rows were formed analogously using 5,7,9,11,13,15,17 sublists each beginning with $r_1.$ The averages of the sublists are given in each row.  They sum to 3,5,7,..., *suggesting* the mean of the ratios $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$ is 1, that is, that the average number of primes for $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,... \}$ is $\sim \pi(n).$

\begin{array}{ccc}
1, 1/2, 3/2  \\
5/4, 3/4, 3/4,5/4,1  \\
5/6,7/6,5/6,5/6,1,7/6,7/6\\
1,1/2,3/2,1,1/2,3/2,1,1/2, 3/2 \\
11/10,1,9/10,11/10,9/10,9/10,9/10,11/10,11/10,11/10,9/10\\
11/12,13/12,13/12,11/12,11/12,11/12,11/12,13/12,13/12,11/12,13/12,1,13/12\\
10/8, 3/8, 9/8, 10/8, 4/8,15/8,6/8,3/8,15/8,1, 5/8, 9/8,6/8,5/8,12/8\\
17/16 ~~~\text{(8 times)},15/16 ~~~\text{(8 times) },1 
\end{array}

(1) Absent a proof the rounding of decimals into fractions is conjectural.

(2) *The calculation is not very sensitive to M. $m = 0,1,2,..., M = n/2 seems to work but I think there must be a better choice.

(3) I posted the table earlier without context. Hopefully the context and a specific question clarifies the question somewhat

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Your notation is not helpful. In the first appearance of $A$, is $m$ fixed? So it's really $A(m,n)=\#\{{\,x\lt n:x^2+x+5+6m{\rm\ is\ prime\,}\}}$? If $m$ is not fixed, then presumably $A$ is infinite.  Or maybe $x$ is fixed? Incomprehensible.

Comment: What do you mean, "we could not exceed $n$"? All I see is that $x$ cannot exceed $n$, and why would this cap $m$?

Comment: Ah, you meant the *primes* in question couldn't exceed $m$, you just didn't want people to know....

Comment: I still can't get past the first few sentences. Is $A$ a set of primes, or the number of primes in some set? Is $A$ the same as $A(m,n)$, or is it something different? It's still not clear whether $m$ is fixed. Maybe you ought to write out some examples (at least, for yourself) to clarify what you want.

Comment: So, I think you are now saying, $A(2000,0)=308$, $A(2000,1)=507$. This suggests that $A(n,m)$ depends heavily on $m$. If that's so, then presumably the limit on $n$ of $A/B$ will also depend on $m$.

Comment: Changed the problem again. I think I'll come back in two weeks. Maybe by then you will have figured out what you want to ask, and how to ask it so that someone other than yourself can understand it.

Comment: The next time you edit the question, please also change the title so it does not [consist entirely of math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1204/856).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the quantity $x^2+x+(5+6m)$ is never a multiple of $3$, while for any $m$, the quantity $x^2+x+(3+6m)$ is a multiple of $3$ for exactly $2$ out of every consecutive $3$ values for $x$. In other words, the "A" set has three times as many numbers that are not multiples of $3$ than the "B" set does.

The [Bateman-Horn conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture) asserts that the number of prime values of a polynomial can be predicted by knowing how many of its values are multiples of $2$, of $3$, of $5$, of $7$, etc. Since you are averaging over lots of $m$-values in arithmetic progressions modulo $6$, only the primes $2$ and $3$ should matter over the long term. This is the explanation of the ratio of $3$ that you are getting. (Note that you could use the Bateman-Horn conjecture to calculate the conjectural ratio for any two polynomials in $x$, even when $x$ is fixed.)

It might even be possible to prove this ratio unconditionally, since you are averaging both over $x$ and $m$ (and the $m$-dependence is linear).

Comment: Thank you, the B-H conjecture is new to me. As you understood the question, any suggestions you might have for improving the first few lines would be appreciated. I added sums over m which I thought made things clearer but this question has been difficult for me to articulate clearly.